# How to force 3 figures into 1 row

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfig

I have 3 figures that at the moment are placed in two rows. How can I force them into a single row? I have tried changing the width of the figures, but that did not make a difference.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[top=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
% Scriptsize axis style.
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},font=\scriptsize,ylabel near ticks,xlabel near ticks,grid=major}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \subfigure[Sigmoid]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=5.5cm,height=4cm,ylabel=$\sigma(z)$,xlabel=$z$,ymin=0,ymax=1.25,xmin=-5,xmax=5]
                \addplot[blue,smooth] {1/(1+exp(-x))};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subfigure[Tanh]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=5.5cm,height=4cm,ylabel=$\tanh(z)$,xlabel=$z$,ymin=-1.25,ymax=1.25,xmin=-5,xmax=5]
                \addplot[blue,smooth] {tanh(x)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }\\
    \subfigure[ReLU]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=5.5cm,height=4cm,ylabel=$s(z)$,xlabel=$z$,ymin=-1,ymax=1.25,xmin=-5,xmax=5]
                \addplot[samples=500, blue] {max(0, x)};
                %\addlegendentry{ReLU}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Credits to [David Stutz](https://github.com/davidstutz/latex-resources/blob/master/pgfplots-activation-functions/activation-functions.tex) for the original figures.

Comment: The `subfigure` package is considered obsolete. You might want to use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: To get rid of the linebreak, remove the `\\ ` in `\end{tikzpicture}
    }\\
    \subfloat[ReLU]{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the linebreak between the second and third image, I have removed the `\\` in the makred line (See `% <------` in the code.) I have also replaced the obsolet `subfigure` package by the newer `subfig` package and changed from `\subfigure` to `\subfloat` commands accordingly. Lastly, I have slightly decreased the width of your tikspictures from `width=5.5cm` to `width=5.25cm` to make sure that your three images in a single row fit into the margins:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[top=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
% Scriptsize axis style.
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},font=\scriptsize,ylabel near ticks,xlabel near ticks,grid=major}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Sigmoid]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=5.25cm,height=4cm,ylabel=$\sigma(z)$,xlabel=$z$,ymin=0,ymax=1.25,xmin=-5,xmax=5]
                \addplot[blue,smooth] {1/(1+exp(-x))};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \subfloat[Tanh]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=5.25cm,height=4cm,ylabel=$\tanh(z)$,xlabel=$z$,ymin=-1.25,ymax=1.25,xmin=-5,xmax=5]
                \addplot[blue,smooth] {tanh(x)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }      %<------------
    \subfloat[ReLU]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=5.25cm,height=4cm,ylabel=$s(z)$,xlabel=$z$,ymin=-1,ymax=1.25,xmin=-5,xmax=5]
                \addplot[samples=500, blue] {max(0, x)};
                %\addlegendentry{ReLU}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only thing still left is getting the subcaptions to centre under the figures. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @bjornvandijkman: You're welcome. The subcaptions are already horizontally centered. However they also take into account the label of the vertical axis. Thisi is why the subcaption seems to be shifted to the left.